# How to convert a Hex to image

Tags: image, hex, imagemagick-convert

Can anyone help me with this. Already tried this website https://onlinehextools.com/convert-hex-to-image, But I couldn't able to download the converted file from it.

Comment: A hex what, please?

Comment: yes, hexa decimal to image!